# Anaconda3 - AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'rsplit'

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I am running Anaconda3 locally via web browser. Everytime I go to the "Conda" section to see the packages that are installed (at http://localhost:8888/tree#conda) I get `An error occurred while retrieving installed packages. Internal Server Error`.

Checking the logs, this is what is currently happening. Any ideas?

```
[E 13:53:08.195 NotebookApp] 500 GET /conda/environments/root?_=1484574786374 (127.0.0.1) 760.41ms referer=http://localhost:8888/tree?
[E 13:53:14.557 NotebookApp] Unhandled error in API request
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-

    packages/notebook/base/handlers.py", line 503, in wrapper
            result = yield gen.maybe_future(method(self, *args, **kwargs))
          File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nb_conda/handlers.py", line 62, in get
            self.finish(json.dumps(self.env_manager.env_packages(env)))
          File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nb_conda/envmanager.py", line 124, in env_packages
            "packages": [pkg_info(package) for package in data]
          File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nb_conda/envmanager.py", line 124, in <listcomp>
            "packages": [pkg_info(package) for package in data]
          File "/root/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/nb_conda/envmanager.py", line 16, in pkg_info
            name, version, build = s.rsplit('-', 2)
        AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'rsplit'
    [E 13:53:14.558 NotebookApp] {
          "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.8,es;q=0.6",
          "Connection": "keep-alive",
          "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
          "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36",
          "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, sdch, br",
          "Cookie": "_xsrf=2|0e84028c|becasdfafdssffjkafdsjkf473451bfcb|1484574343; username-localhost-8888=\"2|1:0|10:1484574347|23:username-localhost-8888|44:ODBlMWE5Mjk1MjRiNDNmNDhkZTVkNTU5MGI3NTNmNDQ=|83dad5a9e1aa2da460539882d41f5b3a7ac93163dab3b324526b730be88d7d69\"",
          "Referer": "http://localhost:8888/tree?",
          "Host": "localhost:8888",
          "Accept": "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01"
        }
    [E 13:53:14.559 NotebookApp] 500 GET /conda/environments/root?_=1484574792779 (127.0.0.1) 750.79ms referer=http://localhost:8888/tree?
```

Comment: I had the same problem when trying to manage kernels for different environments. Installing `nb_conda_kernels` seemed to have fixed it for me: `conda install -c conda-forge nb_conda_kernels`

Comment: This solved my problem. Thanks!

Comment: @motivic You should convert it to an answer actually. It helped me too...

Comment: @Benjamin Based on motivic's idea, I've created [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44691762/3345375). It helped me as well!

Answer (score 7):

Maybe this should be a comment, but I don't have enough reputation for those.

This is a [reported bug in nb_conda](https://github.com/Anaconda-Platform/nb_conda/issues/39). The format of the output of conda's package info has changed and nb_conda has to be adapted. There already is a [pull request that fixes this](https://github.com/Anaconda-Platform/nb_conda/pull/42) but I couldn't find the change in any channel.

**Installing the branch including the fix helps for now:**

`pip install git+https://github.com/Anaconda-Platform/nb_conda.git@d488d9e --upgrade`

The `--upgrade` is optional, I needed it because what I had installed had the same version.

Installing `nb_conda_kernels` (which might have pulled in `nb_conda` as a dependency) from the `conda-forge` channel as mentioned by [motivic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1058545/motivic) did not help in my case, but should work if the package there contains the fix.

Comment: I'm getting this error, regardless of pulling the branch with the fix.

Comment: Is there a way I can still set the default environment with conda for jupyter notebook?

Comment: @RyderBergerud I can't really help you without further information, the fix is in the branch and works for me. I'd also assume, that jupyter is not executing in the right environment. See [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37085665/in-which-conda-environment-is-jupyter-executing) for conda environments and jupyter.

Comment: Just a small note, the branch was deleted 3 days ago after the PR to fix it was merged, so the proper way to install is now `pip install git+https://github.com/Anaconda-Platform/nb_conda.git@d488d9e --upgrade`

Answer (score 2):

Motivic's suggestion (in his comment on the question) worked for me.

```
$ conda install -c conda-forge nb_conda_kernels
```

I already had an older version of nb_conda_kernels, so it updated to 2.1.0.

```
The following packages will be UPDATED:
    nb_conda_kernels: 2.0.0-py27_0 --> 2.1.0-py27_0 conda-forge
```

The Conda tab in Jupyter Notebook worked fine after that. I was also able to `conda install pandas` which had been giving me an error earlier.

Answer (score 2):

I too was having this issue (conda 4.3.25, Linux Mint 17.2 Rafaela, Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS, Trusty Tahr). I attempted the usual update remedies to no avail so I patched the code on line 16 of **.../site-packages/nb_conda/envmanager.py**.

```
    name, version, build = s.rsplit('-', 2)
```

becomes:

```
    if isinstance(s, dict):
        s = s['dist_name']
    name, version, build = s.rsplit('-', 2)
```

This was helpful to me, YMMV. Note that the current [envmanager.py](https://github.com/Anaconda-Platform/nb_conda/blob/master/nb_conda/envmanager.py) in [Github](https://github.com/Anaconda-Platform/nb_conda) has a similar fix based on the dictionary contents.

Answer (score 1):

While I clicked the conda tab in Jupyter Notebook, it always threw the same error as you had.

All the solutions on Stackoverflow and github can't help me out, so in desperation I found on the Anaconda Doc this line (on [the Doc page of conda extension](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/use-jupyter-notebook-extensions#uninstalling-the-extensions)):

> NOTE: These extensions were already installed in Anaconda versions 4.1
>   and 4.2. If you have Anaconda v4.1 or v4.2 installed, there is no need
>   to install them separately. To begin using them, open a new or
>   existing notebook.

Check whether your Anaconda is later than version 4.2. Mine is 4.4.0.

```
W.Zhan Lesson 1 Data Analysis Process $ conda remove nb_conda
Fetching package metadata .........
Solving package specifications: .

Package plan for package removal in environment /Users/W.Zhan/anaconda:

The following packages will be REMOVED:

    _nb_ext_conf:     0.4.0-py36_1
    nb_anacondacloud: 1.4.0-py36_0
    nb_conda:         2.2.0-py36_0
    nbpresent:        3.0.2-py36_0

Proceed ([y]/n)? y

W.Zhan Lesson 1 Data Analysis Process $ python --version
Python 3.6.1 :: Anaconda 4.4.0 (x86_64)
```

Thus I uninstalled conda in terminal, and just activate the environment I wanted to use and in that particular environment, open Jupyter.

```
W.Zhan Lesson 1 Data Analysis Process $ source activate DAND
(DAND) W.Zhan Lesson 1 Data Analysis Process $ jupyter notebook
```

Not sure whether this can solve your problem, for me, although there is no more 'conda' tab in Jupyter, but as long as I can use customized environment in Jupyter, I am fine with that.

Hope it helps.