# conda menu in jupyter notebook from any environment

Tags: python, ipython, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, conda

Trying to install `nb_conda` (as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42585283/5576434)) in root environment, so I wouldn't need to install it in each environment separately, but I'm getting the error:

```
Downloading and Extracting Packages
nb_conda_kernels 2.1.0: ################################################ | 100% 
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: failed
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(481): An error occurred while installing package 'defaults::nbpresent-3.0.2-py36h5f95a39_1'.
PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied')
Attempting to roll back.

Rolling back transaction: done

PermissionError(13, 'Permission denied')
```

Tried installing `ipykernel` in one environment (as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43617958/5576434)), but in other conda environments I don't see conda tab when I run jupyter notebook.

Don't know if I'm missing something, but I would like a nice pointer how to have conda menu in jupyter notebook from any environment without some hassle each time I create new environment.

Clean installed Anaconda 4.4.10, on Ubuntu 17.10.

Comment: If you install `ipykernel` in each environment, then you should start `jupyter notebook` from the base environment, not from each environment... Would that fix this problem, or do I misunderstand?

Comment: My goal is that when I create an environment I can immediately see it in the list in jupyter notebook, and not install anything additionally. However, I am not sure if this is even possible, given all the searching that I did.

Also, when I just install `ipykernel` in one environment, when I start the `jupyter notebook`, I still don't see the conda menu at the top. I presume `nb_conda` should be installed in the root environment, but then I get that `Permission error` that I mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an answer to my own question. The problem was that when I run an installation script I used `sudo`. After reinstalling Anaconda without superuser permissions everything was working as per SO answers referenced in the question:

- `conda install nb_conda` in root environment
- `conda install ipykernel` in any environment just once, other environments will be listed without separate installation

Comment: The second part seems to install the whole `jupyter` into the environment. Is it expected?