# Jupyter Notebook: How to get rid of buttons at bottom (Present, Slides, Themes, Help)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am using Jupyter Notebook 5.2.2 on Amazon AWS for the first time. When I run a Notebook in my browser (Mac OS Safari 11.0), I see buttons at the bottom of the Notebook. The buttons are for Present, Slides, Themes, and Help. I previously have been using Notebook 4.x and  have never seen them before. How do I get rid of these buttons?

[image]

Here is my Jupyter Notebook "About" information:

[image]

Comment: Only way I've managed to remove these pesky, intrusive buttons is to turn on Slideshow, but then I get an even more annoying "Slide type" dropdown list on the upper right corner of every single cell, and nothing I do will make it go away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to disable these buttons by executing the following command in the conda environment from which I was running the jupyter notebook where they had appeared:

`jupyter-nbextension disable nbpresent --py --sys-prefix`

(see https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/use-jupyter-notebook-extensions#uninstalling-the-extensions)

I think you can run the `jupyter-nbextension` command outside of a conda environment with the same effect though. You might as well not be using conda as you don't mention it, but the AWS machine you are using might have the extensions installed by default. I am unsure about this.

For me, conda's notebook extensions were installed after I executed `conda install nb_conda` in order to have access to conda environments in my notebooks.

(see [In which conda environment is Jupyter executing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37085665/in-which-conda-environment-is-jupyter-executing))

Hope this helps.

Comment: This works. That makes me wonder why it's enabled in the first place. Also, how to re-enable it.

Comment: @horaceT `jupyter-nbextension enable nbpresent --py --sys-prefix` should work to re-enable it. See `jupyter-nbextension --help`.