# No Conda environment when I open JupyterNotebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, conda, environment

I use Anaconda to open a Jupyter Notebook:

[image]

When I open the Jupyter Notebook in the default environment, 'root', everything is all right:

[image]

[image: normal Conda environment]

But there are some mistakes when I open the Jupyter Notebook in the other 
environment.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image: empty Conda environment]

Is there some necessary information I should complement？

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not use images to convey textual information. [Edit] your question to replace them with the respective code. Additionally, questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Without this, your question is off-topic and liable to be closed. Please construct a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and include it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you haven't installed jupyter notebook in that environment. Activate your environment and type `where jupyter`. Most probably, you'll see `C:\Software\Anaconda\Scripts\jupyter.exe`

Then type `path`. You should see something like `PATH=c:\Software\Anaconda\envs\<your env>;  ... long output ;c:\Software\Anaconda; ...`

The cmd interpreter searches for `jupyter` executable first in current directory, then in directories, listed in `PATH`. It launches the first one, which it has found.

That's why first entries in `PATH` are related to your environment.

If the `jupyter` will be found somewhere else, it will be successfully launched, but obviously will have no idea about your separate environment.

This can be solved by `conda install jupyter` in your environment.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37085665/704329)