# How to calculate time difference between two pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

My df looks like,

```
    start               stop
0   2015-11-04 10:12:00 2015-11-06 06:38:00
1   2015-11-04 10:23:00 2015-11-05 08:30:00
2   2015-11-04 14:01:00 2015-11-17 10:34:00
4   2015-11-19 01:43:00 2015-12-21 09:04:00

print(time_df.dtypes)

start       datetime64[ns]
stop        datetime64[ns]
```

dtype: object

I am trying to find the time difference between, stop and start.

I tried, `pd.Timedelta(df_time['stop']-df_time['start'])`
but it gives `TypeError: data type "datetime" not understood`

`df_time['stop']-df_time['start']` also gives same error.

My expected output,

```
 2D,?H
 1D,?H
 ...
 ...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need omit `pd.Timedelta`, because difference of times return timedeltas:

```
df_time['td'] = df_time['stop']-df_time['start']
print (df_time)
                start                stop               td
0 2015-11-04 10:12:00 2015-11-06 06:38:00  1 days 20:26:00
1 2015-11-04 10:23:00 2015-11-05 08:30:00  0 days 22:07:00
2 2015-11-04 14:01:00 2015-11-17 10:34:00 12 days 20:33:00
```

EDIT: Another solution is subtract numpy arrays:

```
df_time['td'] = df_time['stop'].values - df_time['start'].values
print (df_time)
                start                stop               td
0 2015-11-04 10:12:00 2015-11-06 06:38:00  1 days 20:26:00
1 2015-11-04 10:23:00 2015-11-05 08:30:00  0 days 22:07:00
2 2015-11-04 14:01:00 2015-11-17 10:34:00 12 days 20:33:00
```

Comment: tried that too, `TypeError: data type "datetime" not understood`

Comment: @pyd - What is your pandas version?

Comment: pandas version '0.19.2'

Comment: @pyd - Is possible upgrade?

Comment: @pyd - It is problem with numpy version, upgrade should help, check [this](https://github.com/facebook/prophet/issues/256#issuecomment-354906674)

Comment: actually I cannot do, my organization firewall blocks pip requests. isin't possible in my version

Comment: ok, I will try upgrade pandas and check, and update you

Comment: Only ine idea - `df_time['td'] = df_time['stop'].values - df_time['start'].values`

Comment: that worked, thank you :)

Comment: how to drop `-` in `-2 days +03:34:00` returned output

Comment: can you tell me, how to open my jupyter notebook on my virtual enviroinment, where I have pandas upgraded version

Comment: @pyd - Then use `df_time['td'] = np.abs(df_time['stop'].values - df_time['start'].values)`

Comment: @pyd - You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37085665) - never do it, so no experience

Answer (score 1):

First make sure that you have dates in your column

```
data.loc[:, 'start'] = pd.to_datetime(data.loc[:, 'start'])
data.loc[:, 'stop'] = pd.to_datetime(data.loc[:, 'stop'])
```

Then substract

```
data['delta'] = data['stop'] - data['start']
```

Comment: I guess it's just a typo, but just to be sure: sometimes you write time_df and other times df_time