# Jupyter notebook not using packages in virtual environment

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I'm using virtualenvwrapper-win to manage environments, I created one, pip-installed a bunch of packages but when I try to import them from jupyter notebook or lab it only looks in the main directory and not in the environments. I tried using the conda environments and had the same problem, so I suspect the problem is in the jupyter configuration, which I haven't meddled with much but might have messed up at some point.

[image: Can't import]

`sys.executable` returns `'c:\\anaconda3\\python.exe'`, but I suspect it should be using the one in the virtual environment right?

Comment: Did you activate the environment?

Comment: I did, and launched jupyter from within.

Comment: Try looking at these: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37085665/in-which-conda-environment-is-jupyter-executing

Comment: installing nb_conda fixed it, as in I can now chose to create a notebook in any of the environments I have created with conda, but not with virtualenvwrapper