# Jupyter Notebook "!" command not using Virtual Environment

Tags: python, shell, terminal, pip, jupyter-notebook

As we all know we can use `!<command>` to ensure the cell runs a terminal command.
However if we use`pip install lxml` it installs `lxml` in the **root python** **kernel** and not the kernel environment that we mention in Jupyter.

With `!`command in `jupyter notebook`, any way to use the python virtual env to install the packages?

```py
if os.name=='posix':
    !pip3 install wget
    import wget
```

This was the code I was trying to run but it installs in `python-base` and not `venv` selected in Jupyter notebook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In recent versions of Jupyter you can use the magic [`%pip`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-pip) command that will target the current kernel rather than the Python installation that is running the notebook.

```py
if os.name=='posix':
    %pip install wget
    import wget
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your env used by the notebook [check venv on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQAA8.png).
   Also, your can check your env list ref: [In which conda environment is Jupyter executing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37085665/in-which-conda-environment-is-jupyter-executing)
2. Test import after restarting your `python-base`.

Comment: Thanks for a Quick reply! Appreciate it
I am actually using Python3 venv environment in Jupyter .. Conda envs give 0 issue i am aware