# How to import packages in code environments on Windows

Tags: jupyter-notebook, conda, ipython, environment

I am having difficulty setting up conda environments in Windows. I follow the basic instructions, but it doesn't seem like the kernel is actually using the indicated environment.

For example, I setup an environment:

```
(base) PS C:\> conda create -n playground python=3.11
```

I activate the environment:

```
(base) PS C:\> conda activate playground
```

I setup the kernel for Jupyter:

```
python -m ipykernel install --user --name=playground
```

The kernel appears in the dropdown:
[image]

After selecting the kernel, I can still import packages from the base environment (rather than playground), but I cannot import packages that are installed with the selected kernel.

Comment: You'd need to specify what 'basic instructions' you followed in your post. you should be using conda to do as much as you can as you chose that as your package manager, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43617958/8508004) about how to install ipykernel. Also how are you starting Jupyter? See Question #2 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39070588/8508004).  Also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43197286/8508004) for lots of good advice. Another option to insure the installations of the packages occurs in the right environment where Jupyter is running is to use `%conda install` ...

Comment: <continued> commands from a new cell inside the notebook where you want to use that. The magic install commands insure the installation occurs in the environment consistent with the kernel backing the running `.ipynb`.