# Module Not found during import in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, python-import, python-module

I have the following package (and working directory):

```
WorkingDirectory--
                 |--MyPackage--
                 |            |--__init__.py
                 |            |--module1.py
                 |            |--module2.py
                 |
                 |--notebook.ipynb
```

In `__init__.py` I have:

```
import module1
import module2
```

If I try to import MyPackage into my notebook:

```
import MyPackage as mp
```

I will get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'module1'`. But import works fine if I execute the script outside a notebook: if I create `test.py` in the same directory and do the same as in the notebook the import would work properly. It will work inside the notebook if I use fully qualified name in `__init__.py` (`import MyPackage.module1`).

What's the reason for different import behavior?

I have confirmed the working directory of the notebook is `WorkingDirectory`.

---Update---------

Exact error is:

```
C:\Users\Me\Documents\Working Directory\MyPackage\__init__.py in <module>()
---> 17 import module1

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'module1'
```

My problem differs from the possible duplicate:

1. The notebook was able to find the package, but only unable to load the module. This was inferred from substituting `module1` with `MyPackage.module1` worked well and suggests it may not be a problem related with `PATH`.
2. I cded into `WorkingDirectory` and started the server there. The working directory should be the folder containing my package.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["ImportError: No module named" when trying to run Python script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15514593/importerror-no-module-named-when-trying-to-run-python-script)

Comment: @LouiseDavies I updated my question to address the duplicate issue.

Comment: I have had a similar issue where it was connecting to some old kernel which did not have all of the packages; make sure you have one at a time and that it connects to the default port, 8888.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57903029/6200607 worked for me

Answer (score 34):

I'm pretty sure this issue is related and the answer there will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15622021/7458681

tl;dr the cwd of the notebook server is always the base path where you started the server, no matter was running `import os os.getcwd()` says. Use `import sys sys.path.append("/path/to/your/module/folder")`.

I ran it with some dummy modules in the same structure as you had specified, and before modifying `sys.path` it wouldn't run and after it would

Comment: Do you mean to add `WorkingDirecotry` to `PATH` or `WorkingDirectory/MyPackage`? The latter worked but the former didn't. Is that the expected behavior? And if the `PATH` is where the problem lies, why does using fully qualified name in __init__.py solve the problem?

Answer (score 7):

understand this two functions, your problem will be solved.

```
#list the current work dir
os.getcwd()
#change the current work dir
os.chdir()
```

change the path, and import module, have fun.
sometime it won't work.try this

```
import sys
# sys.path is a list of absolute path strings
sys.path.append('/path/to/application/app/folder')

import file
```

-, -

Comment: os.chdir requires a parameter

Comment: Error: `NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[2], line 1
----> 1 os.getcwd()`

Answer (score 5):

The best way to tackle this issue is to create a virtual env and point your kernel to that virtual environment:

Steps:

1. `python -m venv venv`
2. `source venv/bin/activate`
3. `ipython kernel install --user --name=venv`
4. `jupyter lab`
5. `go to the jupyter lab ->kernel-->change kernel-->add the venv from the dropdown`

Now if your venv has the package installed, jupyter lab can also see the package and will have no problem importing the package.

Comment: This is the most generic solution.

Answer (score 3):

if you face **module not found** on **jupyter environment** you had to install it on jupyter environment instead of installing it on command prompt

by this command(for windows) on jupyter

### !pip install module name

after that you can easily import and use it.
Whenever you want to tell jupyter that this is system command you should put ( ! ) before your command.

Comment: Please don't post duplicate answers on multiple questions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68323070/3749896) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68322977/3749896)). One answer is fine. See [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104227/is-it-acceptable-to-add-a-duplicate-answer-to-several-questions)

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that I used the wrong conda enviroment when using **Vs Code**.

Enter your conda enviroment

```
conda activate **enviroment_name**
```

To check where a module is installed you can enter python interactive mode by writing python or python3. Then importing cv2

```
import cv2
```

Then to see where this module is installed

```
print(cv2.__file__)
```

You will see the installed path of the module. My problem was that my vs code kernel was set to the wrong enviroment. This can be changed in the top right corner for vs code.

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by installing the `import_ipynb` package.

```
pip install import_ipynb
```

Suppose you want to import `B.ipynb` in `A.ipynb`, you can do as follows:

In `A.ipynb`:

```
import import_ipynb
import B as b
```

Then you may use all the functions of `B.ipynb` in `A`.

Answer (score 0):

this happened to me when I moved my journal into a new directory while the Jupyter lab server was running. The import broke for that journal, but when I made a new journal in the same directory I just moved to and used the same import, it worked. To fix this I:

1. Went to the root dir for my project.
2. Searched for all folders labeled “**pycache**”
3. Deleted all “**pycache**” folders that were found in my root and subfolders.
4. Restarted Jupyter lab server

Once Jupyter lab restarts and compiles your code, the “**pycache**” folders will be regenerated. Also the pycache folders have two leading and trailing “_”, but stackoverflow is formatting the pycache’s without them

Answer (score 0):

The best solution by far (for me) is to have a kernel for each environment you are working in. Then, with that kernel defined, all you have to do is to update this kernel's environment variables to look at your project folder where your modules are located.

Steps (using `pip`):

1. `pip install ipykernel` (if not installed already)
2. `source activate <your environment name>`
3. `python -m ipykernel install --user --name <your environment name> --display-name "<a display name>"` (where  is the name you want to give to your kernel and  is just a name used for display by jupyter.
4. Once you ran the command above, it will output the location of the kernel configuration files. E.g.: `C:\Users\<your user name>\AppData\Roaming\jupyter\kernels\<selected environment name>`. Go to this folder and open the `kernel.json` file.
5. Add the following entry to this file:

```
"env": {
   "PYTHONPATH": "${PYTHONPATH};<the path to your project with your modules>
 }
```

Good reference about the kernel install command [here](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html).

Answer (score -1):

The reason is that your `MyPackage/__init__.py` is ran from the current working directory. E.g. from `WorkingDirectory` in this case. It means, that interpreter cannot find the module named `module1` since it is not located in either current or global packages directory.

There are few workarounds for this. For example, you can temporarily override a current working directory like this

```
cwd = os.getcwd()
csd = __path__[0]
os.chdir(csd)
```

and then, after all a package initialization actions like `import module1` are done, restore "caller's" working directory with `os.chdir(cwd)`.

This is quite a bad approach as for me, since, for example, if an exception is raised on initialization actions, a working directory would not be restored. You'll need to play with `try..except` statements to fix this.

Another approach would be using relative imports. Refer to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references) for more details.

Here is an example of `MyPackage/__init__.py` that will work for your example:

```
from .module1 import *
```

But it has few disadvantages that are found rather empirically then through the documentation. For example, you cannot write something like `import .module1`.

---

**Upd:**
I've found this exception to be raised even if `import MyPackage` is ran from usual python console. Not from IPython or Jupyter Notebook. So this seems to be not an IPython itself issue.