# Pyautogui not importing "No module named 'pyautogui' "

Tags: python, anaconda, python-import, pyautogui

```
import pyautogui

print("hello")
```

After running this I am presented with the following:

```
C:\Users\Darkm\Anaconda3\envs\PythonChallenges\python.exe C:/Users/Darkm/PycharmProjects/PythonChallenges/Automation1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Darkm/PycharmProjects/PythonChallenges/Automation1.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pyautogui
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyautogui'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Could somebody help me understand why I cannot import pyautogui?

Some background information:

1.) I only have one version of python (3.7.4)

2.) I have already installed the module through "pip install pyautogui" in cmd prompt.

3.) Pyautogui is installed under C:\Users\Darkm\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages

4.) Pyautogui does not show up when I go into file > settings > project interpreter and try to add it 
manually (it just doesn't show up).

5.) Have restarted computer multiple times

At this point I cannot figure out why I'm unable to import pyautogui, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

**Why are you getting this error?**

Because you are using **PyCharm.**

In PyCharm you don't need to install python packages from command prompt, in PyCharm you need to install python packages from PyCharm Project Interpreter.

Here are some tips that can help you!

Step 1: Go to PyCharm settings and go to this directory: **Preferences and select Interpreter Settings**

Screenshot:

[image]

Step 2: Click on this plus icon.

Screenshot:

[image]

Step 3: Type your package name and select package.

Screenshot:

[image]

Step4: Then click on install button.

[image]

Step 5: Click on okay

Then wait for two to three minutes and try again.

Hopefully it'll work.

Answer (score 1):

You and also do this trick on imports

```
import subprocess

try:
    import pyautogui
except ImportError:
    subprocess.call("pip install pyautogui")`
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because of pycharm.

If it's not pycharm and you still have problems you can try:

Cmd:

```
python -m pip install < module >
```

To append to PYTHONPATH:

IDE:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('< path >')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you face **module not found** on Jupyter environment you had to install it on Jupyter environment instead of installing it on command prompt

by this command (for windows)

```
!pip install pyautogui
```

After that you can easily import and use it.
Whenever you want to tell Jupyter that this is system command you should put `!` before your command.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the latest version of  python installed on your computer

**On Windows**:

Open up **Windows PowerShell**. Type `py -m pip install pyautogui` and wait for **2 minutes**. Then, restart your **IDE**. Try running your code, it should work now.

**On a Mac**:

Open up **iTerm**. Type `pip3 install pyautogui` or `py -m pip3 install pyautogui`, and wait for **2 minutes**. Then, restart your **IDE**. Then just simply try to run your code, it should be working.

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
# Install a pip package in the current Jupyter kernel
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install numpy
```

[Tutorial from Pythonic Perambulations](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2017/12/05/installing-python-packages-from-jupyter/)

Answer (score 0):

Go to terminal.
type "pip install pyautogui"

```
pip install pyautogui
```

Your problem should be solved now.
If it isn't try this.

```
!pip install pyautogui
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using Pycharm IDE. To install packages in Pycharm, you can use the project interpreter in settings or type the following in the terminal:

`pip install pyautogui`

Answer (score 0):

make sure that library is installed in same version of python