# How come after I install pyautogui it won't import and says No module named 'pyautogui'

Tags: python, pyautogui

After I install pyautogui through pip using `py -m pip install pyautogui`. I try to import it into Pycharm using `import pyautogui` but it just says "No module named pyautogui". I have tried uninstalling python and pyautogui and reinstalling them. I am very new to python so sorry if this makes no sense or is really easy to fix, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Check this answer i believe it is what u need

It's some other guy asking same thing
[how to install packaging](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58892542/20056163)

Answer (score 0):

If you already have another Python installed try view the version of your Python

```
python -V
```

ex.: Python 3.90

try :

```
pip3.9 install pyautogui
```