# Anaconda environment on Windows Subsystem for Linux as python interpreter in PyCharm and kernel in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pycharm, anaconda, windows-subsystem-for-linux

## Summary

I would like to use an anaconda environment living in Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) as a python interpreter for PyCharm and as a kernel for Jupyter Notebook.

## What I've tried

I have an anaconda environment called `tacs-v2` on my WSL (Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS). I created this environment in order to install an open source finite-element code called [TACS](https://github.com/smdogroup/tacs), which can only be compiled on Linux (hence the use of WSL).

I would like to use PyCharm as IDE for some python scripts related to TACS and I have been able to  configure `tacs-v2` as a remote interpreter in my PyCharm Professional on Windows following [these instructions](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-wsl-as-a-remote-interpreter.html#configure-wsl).

I would also like to create some Jupyter Notebooks related to TACS. I first tried to use PyCharm (on Windows) as editor of a Jupyter Notebook, however I got the following error when I executed it:
[image]

When I tried to configure the interpreter for the Jupyter Server I found out that for some reasons my remote interpreter `tacs-v2` could not be used:
[image]

With PyCharm not working, I thought about launching the Jupyter Notebook directly from WSL. I followed [this guide](https://towardsdatascience.com/configuring-jupyter-notebook-in-windows-subsystem-linux-wsl2-c757893e9d69) and I managed to succesfully run the notebook, with one caveat though. At the beginning of my notebook, the following import statement was initially causing a `ModuleNotFoundError`:

```
from tacs import TACS, elements, constitutive, functions
```

where `tacs` is the package constituting the finite-element code and it corresponds to a directory inside the local repository. See below for a representation of its structure:

```
tacs-2.0.0/
|-- build/
|-- docs/
|-- examples/
|-- ...
|-- tacs/
    |-- __init__.py
    |-- constitutive.cpp
    |-- constitutive.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
    |-- constitutive.pxd
    |-- constitutive.pyx
    |-- ...
```

Running the same import statement in a python script with PyCharm was fine. I found the solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43122290/6583606). In fact, running

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

returned different results with PyCharm (Windows) and Jupyter (WSL). The former returned

```
['/mnt/c/Users/qa21944/git/tacs-2.0.0/examples/crm',
 '/mnt/c/Program Files/JetBrains/PyCharm 2021.2.2/plugins/python/helpers/pydev',
 '/mnt/c/Users/qa21944/git/tacs-2.0.0',
 '/mnt/c/Program Files/JetBrains/PyCharm 2021.2.2/plugins/python/helpers/pycharm_display',
 '/mnt/c/Program Files/JetBrains/PyCharm 2021.2.2/plugins/python/helpers/third_party/thriftpy',
 '/mnt/c/Program Files/JetBrains/PyCharm 2021.2.2/plugins/python/helpers/pydev',
 '/mnt/c/Users/qa21944/AppData/Local/JetBrains/PyCharm2021.2/cythonExtensions',
 '/mnt/c/Users/qa21944/git/tacs-2.0.0/examples/crm',
 '/home/fmamitrotta/anaconda3/envs/tacs-v2/lib/python38.zip',
 '/home/fmamitrotta/anaconda3/envs/tacs-v2/lib/python3.8',
 '/home/fmamitrotta/anaconda3/envs/tacs-v2/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
 '/home/fmamitrotta/anaconda3/envs/tacs-v2/lib/python3.8/site-packages',
 '/mnt/c/Program Files/JetBrains/PyCharm 2021.2.2/plugins/python/helpers/pycharm_matplotlib_backend',
 '/home/fmamitrotta/anaconda3/envs/tacs-v2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/extensions']
```

while the latter returned

```
['/mnt/c/Users/qa21944/git/tacs-2.0.0/examples/crm',
 '/home/fmamitrotta/anaconda3/envs/tacs-v2/lib/python38.zip',
 '/home/fmamitrotta/anaconda3/envs/tacs-v2/lib/python3.8',
 '/home/fmamitrotta/anaconda3/envs/tacs-v2/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload',
 '',
 '/home/fmamitrotta/anaconda3/envs/tacs-v2/lib/python3.8/site-packages',
 '/home/fmamitrotta/anaconda3/envs/tacs-v2/lib/python3.8/site-packages/IPython/extensions',
 '/home/fmamitrotta/.ipython']
```

So I had to add `sys.path.append('/mnt/c/Users/qa21944/git/tacs-2.0.0')` before the import statement in my notebook.

## Questions

- [Microsoft docs recommed against working across operating systems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/filesystems#file-storage-and-performance-across-file-systems). As a consequence, I would say that my setup of having the anaconda environment on WSL and the local repository and PyCharm on Windows is not ideal. Since I cannot avoid using WSL, can I have everything there? Unfortunately, it seems that the only way to use PyCharm with WSL is to have PyCharm Professional on Windows and configure a remote interpreter via WSL.
- Why doesn't PyCharm let me set a remote interpreter (my `tacs-v2`) as interpreter of a Jupyter Server?
- Why do I get a different output running `print(sys.path)` with PyCharm (on Windows) and Jupyter (on WSL)? Is there a way I can avoid to manually add the path to the `tacs-2.0.0` directory in my notebook before the import statement?