# Jupyte Notebook

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook, read-csv

When I try to read csv file in my Jupyter notebook, it works for one jupyte_file but the same csv_data_file cannot be read from another jupyteNotebook file. It gives a 'ModuleNotFoundError'

please guide me anyone?

I try to read same csv file in multiple jupyteNotebook files.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Module Not found during import in Jupyter Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43120112/module-not-found-during-import-in-jupyter-notebook)

Comment: Hi @Haroon . Please, explain deeply the problem. Share the code. Correct The typo. Otherwise there's no way to help you.