# Jupyter Notebook: module not found even after pip install

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have a module installed in my Juyter notebook

```
!pip install gensim

Requirement already satisfied: gensim in /home/m.gawinecki/virtualenv/la-recoms/lib/python3.7/site-packages (3.8.2)
```

However, when I try to import it, it fails

```
import gensim

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-e70e92d32c6e> in <module>
----> 1 import gensim

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gensim'
```

It looks like it has been installed properly:

```
!pip list | grep gensim

gensim             3.8.2
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: check whether it is installed in 3.8 or 3.7?

Comment: I think the reason is I am mixing virtualenv with conda, using both `pip install gensim` and `conda install gensim`

Comment: are you calling it outside the virtualenv?

Comment: @classicdude7 I was calling Jupyter notebook installed via conda, but other dependencies I have installed in my virtualenv.

Comment: What helped was `conda deactivate` and the running `jupyter notebook` from active virtualenv.

Comment: In Jupiter 6.3.0 I just entered `pip install gensim` and `pip install python-Levenshtein` as per warning in a notebook cell and then `import gensim` in a new cell worked.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Add your virtual environment as Python kernel in this way (Make sure it's activated):

```
(venv)
$ ipython kernel install --name "local-venv-kernel" --user
```

Now, you can select the created kernel "local-venv-kernel" when you start Jupyter notebook or lab.

You could check the installed libraries using this code in a notebook cell:

```
!pip freeze
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Only this solution worked for me in mac.

Comment: This suggestion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42321784/jupyter-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-matplotlib also works, but less intrusive for ongoing updating an existing kernel.

Comment: I agree. However, I prefer to keep clearly separated and identified virtual environments. It's a good practice.

Answer (score 5):

This has been answerd in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38368318/installing-a-pip-package-from-within-a-jupyter-notebook-not-working):
don't use `!` before pip command because it is executed as in command line, instead use the `%` sign to execute inside the virtual evironment of the current ipython kernel.

Answer (score 1):

Things that could help:

- if using virtualenv / conda or similar python environments: check if you are opening the notebook while being in the correct one. Check your console and activate the right one / deactivate the wrong ones
- uninstall and re-install the package thats causing the problem
- while installing the package check if other packages that you already had are affected, maybe there is some version problem and you need to remove or change other packages