# Using the correct python version

Tags: python, jupyter

Noobie alert, so treat me like I ma 5 yrs old.

I have an Apple MacBook Pro. In the terminal, I can import numpy and other packages. But when I go to Jupyter, not all packages of the console python are available. How do I set it so that Jupyter uses the same python that I use (3.9) in the terminal?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jupyter Notebook: module not found even after pip install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61265125/jupyter-notebook-module-not-found-even-after-pip-install)

Answer (score -1):

You may use “python -m jupyter” instead of jupyter to use jupyter installed on the default python.