# No module named '' even though I installed requirements.txt

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code, pip

I have created requirements.txt file in my directory. Created virtual environment and ran `pip install -r requirements.txt`. In the file I have the following libraries: ipykernel, numpy==1.23.1
pandas==1.4.3, nltk

Everything is installed successfully, here is part of the code:
[image]

But then when I import my libraries in my jupyter notebook I see this error:
[image]

I thought it might be just a problem with numpy but when I commented this line the same error appeared for pandas.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jupyter Notebook: module not found even after pip install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61265125/jupyter-notebook-module-not-found-even-after-pip-install)

Comment: Have you activate your vitual environment? like `source your-virtual-env-path/bin/activate`?

Comment: Yes, I have activated it, but I found out I hadn't selected the right interpreter. After I did that, it all worked out.