# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ipytest.magics'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I am new to Jupyter notebook, and while trying to run the following code:

```
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install pytest
!{sys.executable} -m pip install ipytest

import ipytest.magics
import pytest
```

I ran into the ModuleError. None of the code above that caused any problems. What is the reason for this, and what can I do to solve it?
(My Python version is 3.7.4)

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42321784/jupyter-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-matplotlib

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem. I checked the latest document of ipytest[ipytest document 0.9.1](https://pypi.org/project/ipytest/0.9.1/), it changed the sytle of writing, so i also changed. You can try

```
import ipytest
import pytest

ipytest.autoconfig()
```