# ModuleNotFoundError in jupyter notebook but module import succeeded in ipython console in the same virtual environnement

Tags: python, import, jupyter-notebook, path

I made a virtual env with:

```
$ python3 -m venv /home/jeanpat/Devel/icevision
```

Different modules were installed (pycocotools ...) with pip.

From a virtual environment activated as follow:

```
source /home/jeanpat/Devel/icevision/bin/activate
```

The modules can be imported from an ipython console with no error. When the modules are imported from a jupyter notebook run from the same env (icevision), the immport fails. from a notebook cell,I can run :

```
!pip freeze|grep pycocotools
```

and get the modules list:

```
pycocotools==2.0.4
```

I have:

```
    (icevision) jeanpat:~/ $ jupyter --paths                             [11:06:36]

config:
    /home/jeanpat/.jupyter
    /home/jeanpat/Devel/icevision/etc/jupyter
    /usr/local/etc/jupyter
    /etc/jupyter
data:
    /home/jeanpat/.local/share/jupyter
    /home/jeanpat/Devel/icevision/share/jupyter
    /usr/local/share/jupyter
    /usr/share/jupyter
runtime:
    /home/jeanpat/.local/share/jupyter/runtime
```

The [problem is similar to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42321784/jupyter-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-matplotlib), i try this:

```
$ ipython kernel install --name "icevision" --user
```

but it didn't resolve the problem.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use the command [to solve the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42321784/jupyter-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-matplotlib) in the answer by Peter S. Magnusson:

```
python -m ipykernel install --user --name="myenv" --display-name="My project (myenv)"
```