# I have installed numpy, yet it somehow does not get imported in my jupyter notebook

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter-notebook

I have installed numpy using
pip install numpy
In the current directory.
But when I try to import it in my jupyter notebook, it gives an error.
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_17100/2172125874.py in 
----> 1 import numpy

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'

Please help me resolve this problem. I have tried uninstalling numpy and re-installing, yet it does not work at all. I am using a Windows 10 system.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jupyter ModuleNotFoundError: No module named matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42321784/jupyter-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-matplotlib)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `pip install numpy` will install NumPy package in python/site-package, not the current directory. You can type `pip show numpy` in the terminal to check its information(path, version...).

Secondly, Maybe the interpreter you choose in Jupyter notebook is not the same as the one you installed numpy on. You might need to check that.

To check Whether it has numpy. You might use `pip list` to check that, in case `pip` corresponds to the interpreter you wanna check.

Hope this will help you.