# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'featuretools' even though I have installed featuretools

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, featuretools

I keep getting the error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'featuretools' in Jupyter Notebook. However, it looks like it has been successfully installed when I install it in the terminal. I have tried installing it with pip install featuretools==0.27.0, pip -m install featuretools, and conda install -c conda-forge featuretools==0.27.0. I would appreciate suggestions on how to proceed.

Comment: Please, could you provide more information? Python Version, are you using virtualenvs or just system version of Python?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the featuretools library and the jupyter notebook library are installed in different python environments.  Perhaps check out this question:

[Unable to import a module from Python notebook in Jupyter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33960051/unable-to-import-a-module-from-python-notebook-in-jupyter)

Ensuring the jupyter notebook library is installed in your expected environment may resolve this